# web design question (php/ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, lamp

Hope this isn't a waste of your time. I'm working on a project, and it occured to me that there's a chunk of code out there, that should allow me to see how others have implemented this.

I've got a project where I'm going to have a page, with a sel box. the user will select an item from the selList, and based on the item selected, a separate section of the page (areaB) will change in terms of the content/tbls being displayed.

i then want to allow the user to go through a series of subpages in areaB, where the user goes through a submit/cancel/confirm process, where the stuff in areaB changes, with the rest of the page remaining the same...

i'm trying to figure out the best approach to implement the on both client/server side.

i could just have an ugly "if block" where i have abunch of logic, and i completely regen the page each time the user selects an action..

i could have an approach that might involve divs/frames, where i then just regen the targeted frame/div area.. is this even possible??

i could have some form of ajaxy process, which would only alter the targeted section(s) of the page...

so.. i'm trying to talk to anyone who has ideas on how to do this, or more ideally, if you know of a good code (client/server) side example of this... that i can examine. i'd  really appreciate it!!

i've got a more detailed overview but didn't know if it would be cool to post it here...

thanks..

tom

Comment: Sorry, but SO is best for specific questions. There are thousands of ways to implement this. You can use a framework like CakePHP or just code everything into a single PHP file. You could use tons of JS frameworks like jQuery, mootools etc. It is totally your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i've understood good this can be done in axaj. This is my idea you will have a  where you load the current page with a form. After the submit button is pushed the values from form will be subtmited to an procesor let call it formprocesor.php. In formprocesor.php you will have a case that will check the step where you are in your submited for and will return the corect values to ajax proccessor in the main page. After values are recived, the ajax proccessor will display them in the result 
Here is a little example: http://24ways.org/2005/easy-ajax-with-prototype there are more on a search on google with "ajax prototype tutorial"
Good luck!